# What was this 4th edition paperback character booklet product I used to use?

Tags: dnd-4e, product-identification, character-sheets

Long ago, a friend and I had a 4th edition fillable character sheet. More of a full portfolio, with some twenty-ish pages. I'm pretty sure it was official Wizards merchandise and I've searched on their site for it, but they carry very little products from past editions. It's a long shot, but I would love to get some more of those. What was this, and how or where can I find them?

I can't find a picture of it, but it had a scroll motif on some of the pages (I know, not the most unique thing), had a section for acquaintances and I believe even a blank map section, and was, again, a lot of pages. I want to say around 15 to 20 pages, though it could be closer to 12 with how the mind likes to exaggerate things.

Comment: Hi Korvel, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Rest assured this site by policy refuses to allow people to scoff at your gameplay or game choices (we [embrace a plurality of playstyles](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5174/1204) and [expect members treat each other with respect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)). I've edited this down to focus on the product you're seeking to identify since there's no need to defend those choices. You wouldn't happen to have an old used copy lying somewhere you could photograph, would you?

Comment: Also, we won't be able to recommend you a new similar product -- we don't handle shopping recommendation requests -- so I've removed a part of your question that sounds like it was requesting that. If you'd like to solicit shopping recommendations, you can instead turn to a forum -- [we've collected a list of forums we'd recommend here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: Thank you very much, the edits are appreciated. Honestly, I doubt I'll find it for purchase, but I'll check the forums as well. What surprises me most is that I can't find any pictures or pdfs of it, so I'm hoping someone might know the name or have a used copy to take a picture of to narrow my search. I wish I still had the one I used to use, as I loved the character I used it for as well, but it seems to have been lost, probably during the move a few years back.

Answer (score 2):

You were probably using the ["Dungeons & Dragons Character Record Sheets"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786948531). Released by Wizards of the Coast, it contained several portrait and landscape style Character Sheets and separate cards for your powers and items.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thank you for pointing me in a possible direction.